# hibernate query for getting the table column count

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am new to learning HIBERNATE and SQL.I want a query for count the number of columns available in the table. Please help me to do this task.

I tried the below query,but i am getting bulk manipulation exception.

Thank you.

```
Query colQuery  =   session.createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema =:'dn' AND table_name=:'tn'");
    colQuery.setString("dn", "abc");
    colQuery.setString("tn", "store_data");
  int count=colQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with your code.  First, named parameters in your native query do not take single quotes around them, i.e. use `:dn` and *not* `:'dn'`.  Next, you are trying to execute an update on a `SELECT` query.  This is also wrong, because you are not updating any records, and you just need to call `colQuery.list()` to get back your result set.  Finally, I believe you need to use `Query#setParameter()` to assign values to the parameters.  Try using this code:

```
Query colQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema=:dn AND table_name=:tn");
colQuery.setParameter("dn", "abc");
colQuery.setParameter("tn", "store_data");
List<Object[]> rows = colQuery.list();
int rowCount = ((Integer) rows.get(0)[0]).intValue();
```

Note that I accessed the first row of the result set, and the first (and only) column in that first row to get the count.